# Stop facebook sdk 4.0 login process after a connection timeout

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I have implemented the facebook login code and it is working fine. Now my current problem is that when there is slow internet connection then facebook login takes a lot of time. So I want to implement a timeout let's say 8 seconds. So i am creating a handler which will check that if the user has not logged in after the stipulated time then it will stop the login process.

My question is what code should I write in order to stop the login process? I am unable to find any answers on the net, so please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use @Override onCancel() ,you can call this overrided function and do what you want in callback ...